# Materialize computed column's data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I have a problem where essentially a table where one column is a computed column is very "fragile" and even the slightest changes causes it to break.  I was wondering what some of the most common methods of materializing data from a computed column was (also because computed columns can't be indexed)

For reference, the computed column is spatial data generated by the following statement:

```
geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING('+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),IPStartNumber)+' 0,'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),IPEndNumber)+' 0)',0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter the table maikng the computed column a persisted column.

```
Alter TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ComputedCloumn] AS (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING('+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),IPStartNumber)+' 0,'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),IPEndNumber)+' 0)',0)) PERSISTED
)
GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately in SQL Serv 2008, spatial columns (or any CLR types that are not byte ordered) cannot be PERSISTED.
I will close my question though since I found out what the issue was.

In some cases in the table, there were not true "ranges" of IP addresses.  The "range" was a single IP address so the IP Start and End were the same.  For this reason, the computation of the geometric instance LINESTRING was only receiving one point for construction and thus throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases in the table, there were not true "ranges" of IP addresses. The "range" was a single IP address so the IP Start and End were the same. For this reason, the computation of the geometric instance LINESTRING was only receiving one point for construction and thus throwing the error.